# Where should I add "ing" in the short form?

Tags: slang

RTFM = Read the f***ing manual

I can say to someone "please RTFM" which would mean "please Read the f***ing manual"

How do I say it in short form when I want to say I have done it?

Long: "After **Read**ing **the** **f**`*****ing** **manual**, I understood the concept"

Short: "After **RTFM**ing, I understood the concept" Or "After **R**ing**TFM**, I understood the concept"?

I mean to text, not say it aloud.

---

Edit-

From my intuition, I think the word RTFM (a group of words) acts a verb in the combo. And that makes sense to add *ing* after the word. RTFMing.

Some elaboration would be appreciated if that seems a good point.

Comment: This is extremely colloquial and falls outside the rules of formal English, but a quick google search shows that "RTFMing" is about 30 times as frequent as "RingTFM" on the internet, though both exist. I would personally say "RTFMing", just like I would (informally) say "RSVPing".

Comment: "I _did_ RTFM, and now I understand it." or "I read TFM, and now I got it."

Comment: As I said, "this falls outside the rules". But familiar fixed abbreviations often tend to be treated more like a single word than as their actual expanded versions because people have gotten used to thinking of it as a single concept. "LOLing" is getting common enough that it's sneaking into [informal dictionaries](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loling). Eventually, the original abbreviation can be forgotten altogether (as with "laser" or "scuba" and arguably "RSVP", since I'll bet a large fraction of people who use that last one don't know what it expands to).